# convert short jquery to standalone javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, append, converters

Can you help me getting this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#large").attr("src",bilder[0]);

    $.each(bilder, function(i) {
        $("#gallery .large").append("<div class='small'><table><tr><td><img src='"+bilder[i]+"' /></td></tr></table></div>");
    });

    $(".small td").mouseover(function(){
        var src = $("img",this).attr("src");
        $("#large").attr("src",src);
    });
});
```

I started with this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('large').setAttribute('src', bilder[0]);

    for (var i = 0, len = bilder.length; i < len; ++i) {
    //??? 
    };

});
```

That's what I have, but appending and mouseover...no idea.

Hope you can help me "converting" this.

Comment: `//??? ` that is one of the place where jQuery comes handy :-)

Comment: yes. this is the "hard" party where jquery would be perfect. but in this case, i can not use jquery. only plain js.

Comment: If you are targeting modern browsers you can use document.querySelectorAll for your selections

Comment: i know. like this `var $ = function(el) { return document.querySelectorAll(el); };// Usage = $('.hello');` But is has to be compatible down to IE7 for example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, phew, this comes a little close. Can you try this ?

```
for (var i = 0, len = bilder.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var els = document.getElementById("gallery").getElementsByClassName("large");
    for (var j = 0; j < els.length; ++j){
        els[i].innerHTML += "<div class='small'><table><tr><td><img src='"+bilder[i]+"' /></td></tr></table></div>";
    }
};

...

var smallEls = document.getElementsByClassName("small");
for( var i = 0 ; i < smallEls.length; ++i){
    var tds = smallEls[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for( var j = 0 ; i < tds.length; ++j){
        tds[j].onmouseover = function(){
            var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
            for( var k = 0 ; k < imgs.length; ++k){
                var src = imgs[k].src;
                document.getElementById("large").addAttribute("src", src);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost perfect! I changed the `els[i]` to `els[j]` and the loop works fine! The mouseover is not firing.

Comment: `for( var j = 0 ; i < tds.length; ++j){` to `for( var j = 0 ; j < tds.length; ++j){` and `.addAttribute` to `setAttribute` and it is working (only) on the first mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property `innerHtml` of an element te set its content. To append some content, you should use +=

Ex: `myElement+= "<p>A new paragraph</p>"`

Answer (score 0):

FYI, solved it like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('large').setAttribute('src', bilder[0]);

    for (var i = 0, len = bilder.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var els = document.getElementById("gallery").getElementsByClassName("large");
        for (var j = 0; j < els.length; ++j){
            els[j].innerHTML += "<div class='small'><table><tr><td onmouseover='document.getElementById(\"large\").setAttribute(\"src\", \""+bilder[i]+"\");'><img src='"+bilder[i]+"' /></td></tr></table></div>";
        }
    };

});
```